# Getting npm errors due to outdated TLS: "tls-test" isn't working

Tags: node.js, windows, ssl, npm, tls1.2

I've been getting this message when running `npm i` on my JavaScript VS Code project:

```
npm notice Beginning October 4, 2021, all connections to the npm registry - including for package installation - must use TLS 1.2 or higher. You are currently using plaintext http to connect. Please visit the GitHub blog for more information: https://github.blog/2021-08-23-npm-registry-deprecating-tls-1-0-tls-1-1/
```

The solution that seems to work for a lot of people is to update Windows 10 and then run these commands:

```
npm set registry=https://registry.npmjs.org/
npm install -g https://tls-test.npmjs.com/tls-test-1.0.0.tgz
```

So I did that. The second command above (the one with the tls-test) should give me this response if it works:

```
Hello! The tls-test package was successfully downloaded and installed.
Congratulations! Your package manager appears to support TLS 1.2.
```

Instead, I get this:

```
npm WARN config global `--global`, `--local` are deprecated. Use `--location=global` instead.

changed 1 package in 827ms
```

It seems like it's installing without an error, but still not giving me the correct message. I'm assuming that means my TLS still isn't enabled, so what am I missing here?

Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: What version of npm and node.js?

Comment: I'm using up-to-date node and npm: "node": "16.16.0", "npm": "9.1.3"

Comment: The obvious answer seems to be "Use `--location=global` instead" of `--global`

Comment: I also have this error and have tried the fix above without success.

Comment: hello janae, how did you solve this? what's the expected output when your running, "npm install -g https://tls-test.npmjs.com/tls-test-1.0.0.tgz", are you getting that "Hello! The tls-test package was successfully downloaded and installed.
Congratulations! Your package manager appears to support TLS 1.2." ? i dont get that value neither. thanks

Answer (score -1):

This is what fixed my issue

```bash
npm config set registry https://registry.npmjs.org/
```

Reference:

- https://www.declarecode.com/code-solutions/shell/npm-notice-beginning-october-4-2021-all-connections-to-the-npm-registry-including-for-package-installation-must-use-tls-1-2-or-higher-you-are-currently-using-plaintext-http-to-connect